# Adding a text area in table and saving it to SQL Server database

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I'm using Classic ASP to add a note function to the table that is displaying rows from a database. The inserted row will save to the database saved Remarks but the following code isn't working.

```
<%
   Dim fRemark
   fRemark = Request.Form("Remarks")
   Dim rsIntra,MyQryItr2
   set cnIntra = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
   set MyQryItra2 = server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Recordset")
   set rsIntra = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
   MyQryItra2 = "select Remarks from [PurchaseOrderTrackInfo]"
   rsIntra.Open MyQryItra,strRMSIDMcn 
   if rsIntra.eof then
       MyQryItr2 = "insert into [PurchaseOrderTrackInfo] Remarks values  N'" & fRemark & " '; "
       cast(Remarks as int)
       cnIntra.Execute MyQryItr2
   else
       rsIntra.close
       set rsIntra = Nothing
       set rsIntra = server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
       MyQryItr2 = "UPDATE [PurchaseOrderTrackInfo] SET Remarks = N'" & fRemark & " '; where Remarks = rowID;"    
   end if
   set rsIntra=Nothing
   strConnDB= "Driver={SQL Server};Server=GB;Database=PurchaseOrderTrackInfo;UID=madfox;PWD=;" 
%>
   <td colspan="10" bordercolor=#3399ff bgcolor=#FFFF99 align="center">
       <font face="Arabic Transparent" size="1" color="#800080"></font>
       <form action=UpdatePO1.asp method=post >
       <textarea name="Remarks" cols="20" rows="2" ><%=fRemark%></textarea>
       <input type="submit"  class="btn1" value="save" name="finish"/>
       <input type="hidden" name="rowID" value="ID" />
   </td>
   </form>
<%
```

Comment: Is this Classic ASP or asp.net?  It looks like Classic ASP

Comment: its classic  ASP

Comment: Your HTML `<form>` is invalid it can't start inside a table cell and end outside it, move the `</form>` inside the `</td>`. Did you run the HTML through a validator? Also the line `cast(Remarks as int)` is not valid VBScript syntax and will error, not sure what that is meant to be doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you never execute your update query. also your update statement does not seem to be valid as you are using the column Remarks as storage for the Remark and as row id. consider adding a rowid column to you table and use the following update statement

```
MyQryItr2 = "UPDATE [PurchaseOrderTrackInfo] SET Remarks = N'" & fRemark & " ' where rowId =" & rowID
cnIntra.Execute MyQryItr2
```

Since your code is vulnerabe to SQL injection, you should look up parameterized queries.